# Expected end sub and for control variable already in use errors

Tags: vba, excel

When i try debugging this code, i am getting two errors, the first one saying "For control variable already in use", and the second one "Expected end Sub". the goal of my code is that i created series of checks in my sheet "poteaux" and i want to take values from the sheet "Efforts poteaux" and put them in certain cells in poteaux so that the formulas will be checked. The msg box gives me if it's good or not. i am new to vba and im giving it a try.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    For i = 4 To 15
        Sheets("Poteaux").Range("C4").Value = Sheets("Efforts poteaux").Cells(i, 6)
        Sheets("Poteaux").Range("D4").Value = Sheets("Efforts poteaux").Cells(i, 11)
        If Sheets("Poteaux").Value("I4") = "NG" Then
            Sub Msg_exe()
            MsgBox "NG"
            End Sub
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox "OK"
End Sub
```

Comment: For why did you put `Sub Msg_exe()` in inside of other `Sub` ? why not only put there msgbox on it's own?

Comment: Because it was giving me an error Object doesn't support this property or method, i am not sure if this is relevant to add sub msg_exe()...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
For i = 4 To 15
Sheets("Poteaux").Range("C4").Value = Sheets("Efforts poteaux").Cells(i, 6)
Sheets("Poteaux").Range("D4").Value = Sheets("Efforts poteaux").Cells(i, 11)
If Sheets("Poteaux").Range("I4") = "NG" Then
    MsgBox "NG on " & i
    Exit Sub
End If
Next i
MsgBox "OK"
End Sub
```

Comment: you missed Sheets("Poteaux").Value("I4") = "NG"

Comment: this one always gives me object doenst support property or method on the msgbox line

Comment: I apologize, now I get what Jeeped meant :). I tested the code and it runs as it should now.

Comment: Awesome, glad it works. I would greatly appreciate up voting my answer:)

Comment: do you know how can i add that it gives me the maximum of the cell U57 due to the changement of the i variable?

Answer (score 0):

Do not attempt to nest sub procedures. Code them independently and **call** one from the other.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    dim i as long

    For i = 4 To 15
        workSheets("Poteaux").Range("C4") = workSheets("Efforts poteaux").Cells(i, 6).Value
        workSheets("Poteaux").Range("D4") = workSheets("Efforts poteaux").Cells(i, 11).Value
        If workSheets("Poteaux").RANGE("I4") = "NG" Then
            Msg_exe i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    MsgBox "OK"
End Sub

Sub Msg_exe(i as long)
    MsgBox "NG on " & i
End Sub
```

Comment: this one worked for me, how can i add that the message box gives me on which value of i i got a "NG" check?

Comment: I've added a parameter pass over of the current value of i.

Comment: i received a new error saying Byref argument type mismatch on the line Msg_exe i

Comment: You were not declaring your variables so `i` was a variant. [Start using Option Explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/3554/always-use-option-explicit#t=201607281607357211291).

Comment: do you know how can i add that it gives me the maximum of the cell U57 due to the changement of the i variable?